# Active and passive voice usage for gerunds and infinitives

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive, active-vs-passive

> I saw him go.

What is the passive voice of this?

My book is saying:

> He was seen to go by me.

Why can’t it be :

> He was seen going by me.

Answer (score 1):

These are  two different sentences with different meanings.

> 1. ACTIVE VOICE : *I saw him go.* (it means I saw his entire journey.)

Bare infinitive is used after the verbs of perception in the active voice; but infinitive with 'to' is used in the passive voice in this case :

> PASSIVE VOICE : *He was seen (by me) to go.*

Again,

> 2. ACTIVE VOICE : *I saw him going.* (It means I saw the start of his journey.)
>
> PASSIVE VOICE : *He was seen (by me) going.*